# print only the infopath webpart on a sharepoint 2013 page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have a sharepoint 2013 page with a infopath form. I would like this page to contain a button that only prints the specific form ignoring the rest of the page.

I have found the below script (source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/98da14d4-9447-4665-8b3a-fee558c4809f/print-specific-webpart-of-a-page-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious).The Problem is I don't think I am identifying the "WebPartelementID" correctly.

Script:

```
<input type="button" OnClick="javascript:void(PrintWebPart())" value="PrintWeb Part">
<script language="JavaScript">
//Controls which Web Part or zone to print
var WebPartElementID = "<WebPartElementID>";
//Function to print Web Part
function PrintWebPart()
{
var bolWebPartFound = false;
if (document.getElementById != null)
{
//Create html to print in new window
var PrintingHTML = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';
//Take data from Head Tag
if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)
{
var HeadData= document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD");
if (HeadData.length > 0)
PrintingHTML += HeadData[0].innerHTML;
}
PrintingHTML += '\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n';
var WebPartData = document.getElementById(WebPartElementID);
if (WebPartData != null)
{
PrintingHTML += WebPartData.innerHTML;
bolWebPartFound = true;
}
else
{
bolWebPartFound = false;
alert ('Cannot Find Web Part');
}
}
PrintingHTML += '\n</BODY>\n</HTML>';
//Open new window to print
if (bolWebPartFound)
{
var PrintingWindow = window.open("","PrintWebPart","toolbar,width=800,height=600,scrollbars,resizable    ,menubar");
PrintingWindow.document.open();
PrintingWindow.document.write(PrintingHTML);
// Open Print Window
PrintingWindow.print();
   }
   }
< /script>
```

I am very open to other ways to achieve this if anyone has a better idea

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested I made this script work. Looking at the script in developer tools on chrome the ID you need is