# Print Infopath Webpart on a SharePoint Online Page Using Code

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, printing

I'm trying to save the Infopath web part to pdf and think print should be able to do this for me. (as you can then just select save to pdf)

Similar to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190494/print-only-the-infopath-webpart-on-a-sharepoint-2013-page) which seems to have been answered by the asker but the critical part of the question has vanished.

I found what I assumed was the web part id required (the string after "webpartid=") when inspecting the infopath element but pasting this in place of the  doesn't seem to work.

ie. `var WebPartElementID = "fb1a953f-bbfb-41ae-a60d-a84a1fe70798";`

[image: Webpart ID]

Is there another way to add a print button for an Infopath form in SharePoint Online?  Or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to achieve with the Print button. The way I achieved that usually is to have and Print view in Infopath (sometimes IP form was split into multiple sections that were filled in during different part of workflow, so in Print view we could put all relevant fields) That view as very plain not containing any branding that other part of form might have. And from there you would use normal print option from web browser and route it to pdf printer.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to click this and immediately be prompted to save to pdf but if it did the same as rightclick-print that would be alright.